# How can i protect original product images?

Tags: magento2, product-images

I enabled watermark funtion of Magento, but original files still accessable from url without watermark.

Example:

Cached image url with watermark

`/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/df484df48ez74849c15sd4f7780/f/f/dsf-8f48d4f.jpg`

Original image url without watermark:

`/pub/media/catalog/product/f/f/dsf-8f48d4f.jpg`

So, if someone remove `/cache/df484df48ez74849c15sd4f7780/` from url can access to original photo without watermark to steal images.

How can i protect my original images?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the only way to guarantee the images are permanently watermarked is to edit them before uploading them to your site.

I appreciate this is time consuming thought.

Answer (score 0):

very good solution: [How To Protect Original Product Images In Magento 2?](https://www.tigren.com/protect-product-images-magento-2/)

The simple solution here is modifying and using the following .htaccess file in the /pub/media/catalog directory:

---

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

#The next coding line permits the original images to be accessed by admin end directly

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.yourwebsite.com/.*$ [NC]

#The next coding line permits the watermarked images to be accessed directly. It is according to the rule where the URL does not contain a cache.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/cache/) [NC]

#It is the page where your store visitor will be redirected if they will attempt to access images directly.

RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_shall_not_steal [R,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend setting up Apache/Nginx rules to prevent users from accessing paths inside the `/pub/media/catalog/product/` directory, *other* than `/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/…`